# SystemVerilog: How to connect C function using DPI call in VCS simulator?

Tags: c, system-verilog, synopsys-vcs, system-verilog-dpi

I have the following files:

**C file with functions:**

**// funcs.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void something() {
    printf("something\n");
    sayHello();
}
```

**System verilog file:**

**// hello_world.v**

```
module kuku;
    export "DPI-C" function sayHello;
    import "DPI-C" function void something();
    initial something();
    function int sayHello ();
        $display("hello world");
        sayHello = 1;
    endfunction
endmodule
```

How can I compile it and make this work so when I call `something()` from SV, it will call the C function, and when I call `sayHello()` from C, it will call the SV function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering myself:

When SV code is compiled using VCS, it is first translated into C code.

When `exporting` a function out of SV, it generates a C header file `vc_hdrs.h` that should be included by the C file.

So a change I made in the C file is to add the line:

```
#include "vc_hdrs.h"
```

Then, I just added the C functions file to the VCS compilation command:

```
> vcs -sverilog hello_world.v funcs.c
```

It works!

The output I get is:

```
something
hello world
```

.

Comment: I have to add 'context' in the import statement:
`import "DPI-C" context function void something();`

Answer (score 3):

A solution that works with all simulator that follow [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) is to have `#include "svdpi.h"` and prefix the `extern` keyword in front of all methods being exported to C. **funcs.c** should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "svdpi.h"

extern int sayHello();

void something() {
    printf("something\n");
    sayHello();
}
```

Examples from [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html)

- § H.10.2 *Example 2—Simple packed array application*
- § H.10.3 *Example 3—Application with complex mix of types*

Answer (score 0):

I see you've named SystemVerilog file as .v extension. Not sure if that works or not. But lets say if its hello_world.sv

Your command line should look like this (for Questa Simulator),

```
qverilog hello_world.sv funcs.c
```

"qverilog " is to compile and run SystemVerilog files.

That's all. No need to add extra header files

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have provided a nice example under this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441794/5842403

**Synopsys VCS**

1) You **compile the C code** using flags and introducing the defines you want to add.
In our case our C code need the define PYTHON_PATH

```
#GCC in two steps for shared object
gcc -g -D 'PYTHON_PATH="'$PYTHON_DIR'"'  -fPIC -Wall -I${VCS_HOME}/include -I/usr/include/python2.6/ -lpython2.6 -c ${PROJECTDIR}/verification/PVE/keycontrol/tb/keycontrol_C_code_wrapper.c 
gcc -fPIC -shared -o keycontrol_C_code_wrapper.so  keycontrol_C_code_wrapper.o
```

2) You do the VCS elaboration linking the python lybrary with **-LDFLAGS '-lpython2.6'**

```
vcs -timescale=1ps/1ps -ntb_opts uvm -lca -kdb -full64 keycontrol_tb_top -debug_access+all+reverse  -LDFLAGS '-lpython2.6'
```

3) You run the created simulation file. You call **simv** including **-sv_lib keycontrol_C_code_wrapper** to import the C shared object.

```
#RUN C CODE
./simv -gui -ucli +DVE +UVM_NO_RELNOTES  -l simv.log  +UVM_TESTNAME=keycontrol_basic_test -do ../../verification/PVE/keycontrol/tools/keycontrol_ucli_init.synopsys -sv_lib keycontrol_C_code_wrapper
```